# How to recognize a person from an Image in OpenCv

Tags: java, opencv

I made a program that detects a face from an Image:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

class DetectFaceDemo {
public void run() {
System.out.println("\nRunning DetectFaceDemo");

CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier("C:\\Users\\HM\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\vision\\src\\lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
Mat image = Highgui.imread("C:\\Users\\HM\\Downloads\\john-lennon.jpg");

MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

System.out.println(String.format("Faces detected: %s ", faceDetections.toArray().length));

for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
    Core.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
}

String filename = "detcSuccessful.png";
Highgui.imwrite(filename, image);
    }
}

public class image {
public static void main(String[] args) {
// Load the native library.
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
new DetectFaceDemo().run();
    }
}
```

And i got this:
[John lennon picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrNnS.jpg)

Wanna to recognize the guy who is in the Image by the program and show his name after.

Something like: *Computer: this guy is John.*

Comment: Have you created your train set? I mean the search area that your app decides to search within.

Comment: no, I'm beginner. I've already seen somewhere that theme but dont have any idea of how to do that what you mean.

Comment: See, you need to introduce a pool of faces that your app recognizes. In your case, John Lennon, Robert DeNiro , and so on.. it is called training phase. Then, you can tell your app to decide which person is most likely to be John Lennon. It predicts the face with a confidence it is called prediction phase.

Comment: I see, can you give me an example

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.test8;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

class FaceDetection {
    // Load the native library.
    static{ System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("\nRunning DetectFaceDemo");

        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier("D:\\AntonKONG\\OpenCV\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
        Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("src//data//hkid2.png");

        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

        System.out.println(String.format("Faces detected: %s ", faceDetections.toArray().length));

        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
            Imgproc.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
        }

        String filename = "detcSuccessful.png";
        Imgcodecs.imwrite(filename, image);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I have previously wrote in opencv 2.4 in C++. As I see, you are using JAVA-OpenCV wrapper, so you can easily find JAVA equivalents. In the following code, **image** is vector of images and label is vector of labels. For instace, consider your search space is limited to three persons:

```
0 : John Lenon 
    john1.png  // 100x90 px
    john2.png  // 100x90 px
    john3.png  // 100x90 px
1 : Robert DeNiro
    robert1.png      // 100x90 px
    robert2.png      // 100x90 px
    robert3.png      // 100x90 px
2 : AlPacino
    al1.png    // 100x90 px
    al2.png    // 100x90 px
    al3.png    // 100x90 px
```

0,1,2 are labels and you can see there are 3 faces correspond to each label. Read each image and store it in a Mat object. as below:

```
Mat j1,j2,j3; // John Lennon's faces  :: label 0
Mat r1,r2,r3; // Robert Deniro's faces :: label 1
Mat a1,a2,a3; // Al Pacino's faces :: label 2
```

Create your image vector and label vector as below:

```
images:{j1,j2,j3,r1,r2,r3,a1,a2,a3}
labels:{0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2}
```

then, pass them to the following piece of code.

```
cv::Ptr<cv::FaceRecognizer> model = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
    model->train(images, labels);
    int prediction;
    double confidence;
    model->predict(Frame,prediction,confidence);
```

Sorry for answering in C++ but I'm sure that there are similar. In addition, make sure which version of opencv you are using.

Comment: I tried but I stay at last step, I not know how to pass C++ code to Java. Have you seen a program example in the net that you can give URL

Comment: Which opencv version are you using?

Comment: Got it, you are not using opencv3

Comment: There are many ways you can invoke C++ code within your java code. If you are on Desktop. Therefore, I recommend writing your code in C++. There are many examples that teaches you how to do that. If you are coding in Android, there whole story changes.